# Error using validation form using required and a callback funcion

Tags: codeigniter-3

Codeigniter 3
I am using validation form using required and a callback function.
But it doesn't work, I am in edit controller and view.
When I call the callback function with a cellular that does exist it tells me the cellular exists. But when I try to change the cellular to another it tells me
`You must enter the cellular`, Just cannot change the cellular number to another new one.

```
<php echo form_error('volasoccel' );>
<input value='$volasoc[0]->Celular;  required   type='text' name="volasoccel" class="form-control" id="volasoccel" placeholder="Celular" >


$this->form_validation->set_rules('volasoccel', 'Celular',required| 'callback_volasoccel_check[tvolasoc.TVOLASOC_CEL]|numeric|trim|xss_clean',
                array('required' => 'Debe ingresar el Celular'));
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) - edit your question, and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your required should be enclosed with a single quote:

`'required| callback_volasoccel_check[tvolasoc.TVOLASOC_CEL]|numeric|trim|xss_clean'`